# Can i perform form based http authentication for my TP-Link Wireless Router(IP: 192.168.0.1)

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

Here is the code i trying but it says "Login Fail"(My Defined Message) ... MY wireless Router is TP-Link 740N.

```
 var form = document.forms[0];
    var address = "http://192.168.0.1/";
    var username = "admin";
    var password = "admin";


  var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert("Log In Successful");
            }
            else { alert("Log In Fail"); }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", address, true, username, password);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: https://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/basic-http-authentication-over-xmlhttprequest-ajax/     you are trying to access another domain . not your localhost . is it? then consider CORS  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xmlhttp.open()** is not going to be the tool to do this to access any Router.

Essentially you are trying to do some Web Scraping through a secure website.

If you are trying to do all Web based coding then PHP may be the easiest for this.

Check out **cURL**: http://scraping.pro/scraping-in-php-with-curl/

This will allow you to have a PHP page to do all of the admin bypassing and fetch the HTML of the Router, and you can use xmlhttp.open() to GET/POST to the PHP page.

The trickiest part is knowing how the User/Pass is being checked by the Router.

Most people I know would use possibly a Python Script in the back-end fetching from the Router, or WGET if they are using Linux servers.

Maybe overkill, but if you have Linux, check out Hydra. You can use this tool to hack into Routers and will give you a good understanding of how to approach different Routers to create a Login like you are trying to do.
https://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/